# Are human sounds capitalized like other sounds in the action line?

Tags: screenwriting, capitalization

Such as:

> Bathsheba SNEEZES.
>
> Margaret SNORES loudly.
>
> Katrina SIGHS

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't capitalize those. Capitalization is for emphasis, so make sure you use it very sparingly to draw the audience's attention to SOMETHING very important.

Answer (score 3):

From the sources I've found, capitalizing sounds is optional, and is generally NOT done for sounds made by human beings.  It seems to be a stylistic choice, not a hard-and-fast rule:

https://medium.com/@alli_unger/6-things-to-capitalize-in-your-screenplay-a445e0678aa3

https://gointothestory.blcklst.com/question-what-about-capitalizing-sounds-in-spect-scripts-c4e589c5fbeb

https://screenwriting.io/what-does-it-mean-when-something-in-a-screenplay-is-written-in-all-caps/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure those are verbs, not sounds. They are "human actions which make sounds", but are not sounds themselves.

So even though I am not expert in screenwriting, I would say no.